# moving items of list up and down

Tags: django, django-views

Let's say we have a list of items. And, we want to allow users to control their order by clicking (down-arrow) to lower the order of item one level. And, doing the same to set the order one level higher.

**views.py**

```
def item_up(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=item_id)
    swap_order = item.order - 1
    swap = get_object_or_404(Item, order=swap_order)
    item.order += 1000
    item.save()
    swap.order += 1
    item.order -= 1001
    swap.save()
    item.save()
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

def item_down(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=item_id)
    swap_order = item.order + 1
    swap = get_object_or_404(Item, order=swap_order)
    item.order -= 1000
    item.save()
    swap.order -= 1
    item.order += 1001
    swap.save()
    item.save()
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

this way is working except when I have only two items it shows me an error.

```
No Item matches the given query.
```

Any Idea?

Comment: you are missing a `)` in your question. is it just a copy-paste error ?

Comment: Yes actually it is. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably passing an ID, which does not exist in the database, or the logic of the swap_order was wrong.

This message error is raised when the object does not exist (or not found).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/shortcuts/#get_object_or_404

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def item_up(request, item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    swap_order = item.order - 1
    if Item.objects.filter(order=swap_order).exists:
        swap = Item.objects.get(order=swap_order)
        item.order += 1000
        item.save()
        swap.order += 1
        item.order -= 1001
        swap.save()
        item.save()
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

def item_down(request, item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    swap_order = item.order + 1
    if Item.objects.filter(order=swap_order).exists:
       swap = Item.objects.get(order=swap_order)
       item.order -= 1000
       item.save()
       swap.order -= 1
       item.order += 1001
       swap.save()
       item.save()
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```